# Idris 2 analog to Agda's `rewrite` that also changes types of bindings in the environment

Tags: pattern-matching, idris, dependent-type, idris2

Suppose I have a theorem

```
foo : (n : _) -> (f : Fin (n + 0)) -> ...
foo n f = ?goal
```

and it'd really benefit me if I could use `f` in contexts where `Fin n` is expected (and I really mean the precise term `f` instead of, say, `replace (plusZeroRightNeutral n) f`). How can I rewrite `f`'s type *in the environment* using the appropriate lemma in addition to just rewriting the goal type?

In Agda, I'd just use a `rewrite` (which desugars into two parallel `with`-abstractions), along the lines of

```
foo : (n : _) -> Fin (n + 0) -> ...
foo n f rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n = ?goal
```

Sure, Idris 2 has `rewrite` too, but it only seems to change the type of the goal, without affecting the types of the bindings in scope.

Trying to mimic what Agda does, this is what I've come up with in Idris:

```
foo : (n : _) -> Fin (n + 0) -> ...
foo n f with (plusZeroRightNeutral n)
  _ | eq with (plus n 0)
    _ | _ = case eq of Refl => ?goal
```

I'm first getting the proof of `n + 0 = n`. I cannot pattern-match on it yet (Idris becoming unhappy and saying `Can't solve constraint between: ?n [no locals in scope] and plus ?n 0.`), so what I'm doing next is with-abstracting over `plus n 0`. Now it becomes a single term instead of a function application, both in `f` and `eq`'s types. Now I finally can pattern-match on `eq` (yay dependent case!), getting `f : Fin n` in `goal`'s environment.

This kinda works if I have one such proof I need to apply for such "rewrite". If I have several, it gets really messy. I was hoping at least for an Agda-style parallel `with`, which would be a huge improvement saving some nesting and a `case` match, but I either couldn't figure out the syntax, or the type checker does something funny when I try `with (plus n 0, plusZeroRightNeutral n)`.

So, is there a better way?